# diodes at the output of window comparator

Tags: comparator

[image]

Can anyone explain to me the function of those two diodes?

Comment: Deduce what happens when you remove the diodes (short them) and apply a \$V_{in}\$ for which applies: \$ V_{in} > V_{REF(LOW) } \$ and  \$ V_{in} > V_{REF(HIGH) } \$

Comment: Consider 3 Cases: \$V_{in} < V{ref(lo)}\$, \$V_{in} > V{ref(high)}\$ and \$ V_{ref(lo)} < V_{in} < V_{ref(high} \$.  What does each op-amp output?  What would happen without the diodes?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple form of logic gate called a diode OR. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_logic
http://www.play-hookey.com/digital_electronics/dl_gates.html